# the mirror object in blender 2.8 is not working

Tags: mirror

created mirror in blender 2.8, all other objects seen in render but mirror not reflecting,however in shading mode you can see the reflection.followed instruction from videos step by step in render no mirror signed karlart

Answer (score 1):

make a plane(your mirror) give it a smooth metallic principled shader and then use a plane reflection probe

Here is an example:

[image]

Edit: to make it a perfect mirror make the color white(unlike my example where it's 80% white)
To fix the blurriness either disable screen space reflections or disable Half Res in screen space reflections.
Fixed file:
[image]

Don't forget to enable Rendered mode!